# Erlang function calls - Why does it not work to call self() as a direct argument?

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, function-call

Me and my friend was trying to find a bug with our code for some time when we realised that this was the problem:

```
random_function(spawn_link(fun() -> worker(List, self(), Death) end));
```

This was the solution:

```
PID = self(),
random_function(spawn_link(fun() -> worker(List, PID, Death) end));
```

So my question is, why did it not work to just call the self()-function straight away like that? Is it because it's an anonymous function or is it some kind of special Erlang thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bit more subtle. The `self()` call happens inside the `fun()` which is spawned. Since it it spawned, it has another Pid than the one you expect. Hence, the semantics are different.

Comment: Oh okey so it gets the PID of the anonymous function? But wouldn't that function be called within the process that called spawn_link? Or is the anonymous function first spawned as a separate process and then that one is giving spawn_link its argument instead of the process actually calling spawn_link?

Comment: @Simon No, `spawn_link` spawns a process and then _that process_ executes the function passed as `spawn_link`'s argument.

Answer (score 0):

you  should know that `spawn_link(fun() -> worker(List, self(), Death)` will create a new process, we just call it `Pid1`, then `self()` stands for `Pid1`.

In the second case, you can `Pid = self()` outside the `spawn` function, so `self()` just stand for `Pid`.

Answer (score 0):

When you `spawn/spawn_link` a `fun` then the body of the `fun` is evaluated in the new process, **not** in the spawning process. This is what is happening in your first case, the `self()` call is evaluated in the new process so it does not return the value you want, the pid of the spawning process. However, in your second case you first evaluate `self()` in the spawning process and then pass that pid into the new process, which is what you want.

This is actually a common mistake.